# Possible options for generating reports with/in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, reporting

I would like to know how can I generate reports from Angular JS as front end development language. Nature of the reports are monthly sale reports, monthly order reports, monthly employee performance reports etc

I am using ASP.NET MVC web API as backend development tool.

Note: I have searched online few paid software tools like Syncfusion, ag-grid etc. but my management is finding these tools expensive and is not in the mood to use paid tools. So I would like to know how can I perform the reporting operation in Angular JS without buying any expensive external tool.Kindly provide helpful suggestions for generating reports in Angular JS .

Previously asked questions on this topic were more than 2 years old, so I am inclined to ask for the fresh opinions from experts here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Angular Ui-Grid(http://ui-grid.info) for tabular representations.
For Graphs, i will recommend using D3 or Highcharts

Comment: UI-Grid worked great for me. Thanks